# Xamarin.iOS - How hide or delete a static cell from TableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need to hide or delete a static line from a TableView.

I have tried several methods, but nothing works.

I tried this:

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

    if ( TableView.NumberOfRowsInSection(0) == 9)
    {
        TableView.CellAt(NSIndexPath.FromItemSection(0, 0)).RemoveFromSuperview();
        TableView.ReloadRows(new NSIndexPath[] { TableView.IndexPathForCell(TableView.CellAt(NSIndexPath.FromItemSection(0, 0))) }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
    }
}
```

But doesn't work, the cell continued in the TableView.

I try this:

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

    if ( TableView.NumberOfRowsInSection(0) == 9)
    {
        TableView.DeleteRows(new NSIndexPath[] { NSIndexPath.FromItemSection(0, 0) }, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);
    }
}
```

But this exception is thrown:

> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
>   NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (9) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (9), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

After that, I tried this:

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

    if ( TableView.NumberOfRowsInSection(0) == 9)
    {
        TableView.DataSource.CommitEditingStyle(TableView, UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete, NSIndexPath.FromItemSection(0, 0));
        TableView.DeleteRows(new NSIndexPath[] { NSIndexPath.FromItemSection(0, 0) }, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);
    }
}
```

But now this exception is thrown:

> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
>   NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[DetalheContas
>   tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x7fd49590

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you're trying to remove a cell from your table view from the 'ViewDidLayoutSubviews()' as this will be called numerous times, and hence that cell will not always exist when you try to remove it. I am making an assumption here that it is indeed a cell that you're trying to delete. Irrespective here is an example code snippet for deleting a cell from a table using the 'fade' animation that I can see you using above:

```
YourTableSource.ReplaceSource(SomeData);

SomeTable.BeginUpdates();
SomeTable.DeleteRows(new NSIndexPath[] { NSIndexPath.FromItemSection(0, 0)}, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
SomeTable.EndUpdates();
```

It is worth noting that your source count must differ by the number of delete's that you are committing.

Comment: I have a data that should only appear in a specific condition, remember: I'm using Static Cells. I tried your example but this error appear "Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (10) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (10), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted)"

Comment: I tried on ViewDidLayoutSubviews(), which method should I try to use? ViewWillAppear()?

Comment: Yes 'ViewWillAppear()' is arguably a more practical solution as it should in theory only occur once per initialisation of the UIViewController. The error message you are getting is because you're not removing any items from the tableviews source. Just because they are static does not mean that you cannot remove and re-add them from the Tableviews source. Unless there's a specific reason that you don't want to do this.