# Delete Rows in TableViewController

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I need to expand and collapse rows.When header clicked, calls method *handleExpandClose*.In order to delete rows, I have this:

```
public void handleExpandClose()
{
    var paths = new NSIndexPath[RowsInSection(TableView, 0)];
    for (int i = 0; i < paths.Length; i++)
    {
        paths[i] = NSIndexPath.FromItemSection(i, 0);
    }

    TableView.DeleteRows(paths, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
}
```

Actually I get this:

[image]

Comment: It's because the number of rows you're returning in `RowsInSection` doesn't match after you deleted the rows. (Basically what the error says)

Comment: I believe you need to remove the item from your list before deleting it from the table  try to call tableItems.RemoveAt(indexPath.Row); before deleting

Comment: @yawnobleix,Unfortunately, method tableItems exists in TableSource, but not in TableViewController

Comment: Well you for sure have to find a way to remove the item from your list. You might also need to call begin and end updates see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393728/xamarin-ios-how-hide-or-delete-a-static-cell-from-tableviewcontroller/42907029#42907029

Comment: @yawnobleix thank you, you were right, I figured out all of this. I realized that after  `DeleteRows` program immediately calls `override nint RowsInSection`. So we need also delete items from underlying data source

Comment: no problem glad to help